# Sending a variable to be modified in another class?

Tags: ios, swift

How can one send a variable from a viewcontroller to be modified by another viewcontroller?

I've tried setting the variable in the performSegue, but it does not get modified.

Sample code:

```
class VC1: ViewController{
    var myVar: MyVar

    ....
    prepare(for segue:...) {
        let nextVC = segue.destination as! VC2
        nextVC.var = myVar
    }
    ....
}


class VC2: ViewController {
    var var: MyVar

    ....
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        var = MyVar("newValue")
    }
}
```

After this code is executed, the value of `myVar` in VC1 is not changed to the new value. I believe it only gets a shallow copy of `myVar`, not a deep copy.

Is what I want achievable in swift?

Comment: Just to clarify, you're trying to modify the `myVar` variable in VC1 from VC2, so that when you return to VC1 it has been updated?

Comment: I would recommend to use a service between the two VC's.

Comment: Could you please answer the question of @Jay? Are looking to change variable value when come back to VC1 from VC2 ?

Comment: @Jay yes, that is true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Classes in Swift are pass by reference, whereas structs are pass by value. Assuming that MyVar is a class, you need to modify the properties of the class, ie:

`myVar.property = "xyz"`

instead of defining a new instance of the class as you have done in your question.

Comment: But what if myVar was nil before passing it to VC2? I actually want to instantiate the variable in VC2.

Comment: This is not possible in Swift. You need some sort of reference to the object in order to modify it, nil will not act as a reference for you. You cannot instantiate the variable in VC1 from VC2, you could only ever modify an already defined object.

Comment: Ok I see. Thank you for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

When you set `var = MyVar("newValue")` it assign new instance to `var`.

Comment: var was nil beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

Examine the results from the following code in a playground.  It should give you more insight into what you should expect, without the complication of segues and controllers.

```
class Variable {
    var name:String

    init(_ nameString:String) {
        name = nameString
    }
}

class Sender {
    var myVar = Variable("Start name")

    func showChanges() {
        let receiver = Receiver(myVar)
        print(myVar.name)
        receiver.modify()
        print(myVar.name)
        receiver.replace()
        print(myVar.name)
    }
}

class Receiver {
    var received: Variable

    init(_ variable:Variable) {
        received = variable
    }

    func modify() {
        received.name = "Changed name"
    }

    func replace() {
        received = Variable("New variable")
    }
}

let s = Sender()
s.showChanges()
```